# Take numbers of a string and operate with them

Tags: python, string, integer

I have a string like this one:

```
vserver           volume                                           changelog-usage 
----------------- ------------------------------------------------ --------------- 
svm_name name_of_volume_1 11%              
svm_name2 name_of_volume_2 10%              
svm_name3 name_of_volume_3 0%              
svm_dSN_SM2M_NAS  shorter_name_4                                 15%
```

And I am using this code:

```
matchArr = string.split("\n")
for i in matchArr:
  tmpMatchArr = i.split(" ")
  for i in range(0, len(tmpMatchArr)):
    if int(tmpMatchArr[2].replace("%", "")) < 10:
      break
    if i == 2:
      finalString += " = " + tmpMatchArr[i] + ", "
    elif i == 1:
      finalString += tmpMatchArr[i]
    else:
      finalString += tmpMatchArr[i] + "."
  
print(finalString);
```

The thing is, that I would like to take only those values that are greater than 10, but I am receiving this error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The desired output, is something like this:

```
WARNING: Usage greater than 10% at: svm_name.name_of_volume_1=11%, svm_dSN_SM2M_NAS.shorter_name_4=15%
```

Edit: A regex selecting the numbers, is not an option, because the name of the volume already contains some numbers...

Comment: You could simplify your logic a little by using a regex to match numbers larger than 10 like this: `/[1-9][0-9]+/g` – there's a very useful website to try out regex in realtime here: https://regexr.com/

Comment: You are using `break` where you probably want to use `continue`. Right now your code will stop executing once it hits a value under 10. The code is overall very convoluted and not exactly pythonic, but I think the issue is in the data - try asserting that `len(tmpMathcArr)==3` and see what happens.

Comment: @Labu In this case, the name of the volumes, contains numbers... So I think, that in this case, it does not work for it...

Comment: Also for the last line you might have extra spaces, you need to check with debugging what's going on there; you can also use the Trim String – rstrip(), lstrip(), strip()
to remove spaces in the substrings;

Comment: You could add a space in the regex matcher too: `/ [1-9][0-9]+/g` – if you copy your example log output and this regex into the website I linked, you should see the matches light up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to simplify things a bit you might want to consider regexes:

```
import re

warnings = re.findall('\n(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\d+)\%', string)
print('WARNING: Usage greater than 10% at: '
      + ', '.join('{}.{}={}%'.format(*w) for w in warnings if int(w[2]) > 10))
```

Output:

```
WARNING: Usage greater than 10% at: svm_name.name_of_volume_1=11%, svm_dSN_SM2M_NAS.shorter_name_4=15%
```

Comment: I receive "invalid syntax" at the single comma (after the %, in the print).

Comment: @aldegalan Because you are using Python 2 instead of Python 3 :) Consider to use an updated version, Python 2 is not supported anymore.

Comment: Python 3 is not an option yet... Our machines are using 2.7, so for the moment it is not possible... Do you know if there is an alternative for your solution, that works in Python 2?

Comment: @aldegalan I updated the code to support Python 2 as well. Please mark my answer as accepted an upvote it if you think it is useful, thanks :)